# Is it secure to return php exception message in ajax

Tags: php, ajax, security, exception

The exceptions we throw in our project contain names of stored procedures and classes. Occasionally they contain names of tables, but we should be catching any other critical information. The bullet proof way to do handle exceptions in ajax is to only send the error code with the ajax, however as a programmer it's much easier to debug and maintain code if you pass the messages in ajax (where they may be visible via the network panel).

What are the best practices regarding this in large scale projects?

Comment: SANDBOX env. = send message, PRODUCTION = you may just log it into file

Comment: On dev systems, sure: make it easy for the developer. That's kinda the point. But on production systems, no. Don't make it easy for the developer, because hackers are developers too. It is easy to set things up so that the dev system displays raw errors and the prod system doesn't.

Comment: By the way - for added Dev awesomeness, you should check out FirePHP, which lets you send messages from your PHP code direct to the browser's console. Also needs to be switched off when moving to production, but great for dev work.

Comment: cool! The main time we need to use this is for exceptions (not debugging while writing code) which is where the problem comes in, since people are doing qa our test servers + production, and when an exception happens there it's really helpful be able to check the network tab for the exception message.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no thing as a DEBUG statement. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193044/does-php-have-a-debug-symbol-that-can-be-used-in-code)
There is discussion though on how you could implement a project wide solution to differentiate between DEBUG and PRODUCTION in code, and truth is that you should both for performance (look [here](http://www.litfuel.net/plush/?postid=143)) and security.

An attacker would certainly like to have some information about your database and implementation practices. Table names and field would offer him for example the Number of fields he would need to use on a UNION sql injection query.

Comment: Isn't the bigger problem in that case the fact that someone can do SQL injection in the first place?

Comment: Absolutely, but sql injection will always be a problem no matter what you do. An existing injection point is not always found though. Many exploits out there require the number of columns a table has or some such information. Just look at the execution of the sqlmap tool, and it's options and you will see that most iterations are just the same sql injection technique with different options. Plus you should never give away the dbms technologies or any other technologies you are using. Most attacks begin with googling exploits for specific techs.